# Converting the json output of a console app to a PowerShell object

Tags: json, powershell

Suppose I have a foo.exe console app that returns some json, and I want to turn that into a PowerShell object.

I was hoping to simply write:

```
$o = foo.exe | ConvertFrom-Json
```

But this doesn't work because the output of the console app is treated as an Array instead of a string. I can instead write:

```
$o = ([string]foo.exe) | ConvertFrom-Json
```

which feels dirtier than I was hoping.

**Question**: can I do better than what I have above to get a PowerShell object out of the output of a console app?

Comment: Your second question would presumably be better asked separately....

Comment: @NathanTuggy fair enough, I yanked the second question

Answer (score 1):

As an option:

```
$o = foo.exe | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
```